# Draggable with freezed panel

Tags: jquery-ui-draggable

I am making a draggable image like google map.

This image has grids.  The left column needs to be freezed.  So I output the same image twice. One is the main image.  The other is the freezed column, narrow and on top.

```
.freezed {
  width: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

The size of any grid is unknown, so no snapping to grid.

http://jsfiddle.net/7TMj8/2/

Please advise on how to do the following.  Thanks.

1. On dragging in x direction, only the big one moves.  The narrow one stays.
2. On dragging in y direction, the big one and the narrow one move in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen the [drag](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag) event of `draggable`  to find the moving direction. Set the top position of freezed div using `.css()` on drag.

Script

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    // Narrow one is moving in Y direction while dragging the big one in Y direction
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        var xpos = ui.position.left;
        var ypos = ui.position.top;
        $(".freezed").css('top', ypos);
    }
});
```

Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7TMj8/8/)